# Mapping a function over `frame-list` to get a list of the `top` frame-parameter values

Tags: list, mapping

I'd like to make a list of parameters of each frame such as the top coordinate, left coordinate, and name to achieve what I asked in [my previous question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/29600/switch-to-a-neighboring-frame?noredirect=1#comment45502_29600). I'm trying to follow the advice I got there and wrote a snippet to print the top coordinates of each frame, but it doesn't work. Could anyone tell me which part is wrong?

```
(message "%s" (mapcar (cdr (assq 'top (frame-parameters)))) (frame-list))
```

It returns

```
Invalid function:(mapcar (cdr (assq 'top (frame-parameters))))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that I needed lambda. This worked.

```
(message "%s" (mapcar  (lambda (x) (cdr (assq 'top (frame-parameters x) )))(frame-list) ))
```